# How do I make a link to an image in a slideshow?

Tags: javascript, cycle2

For my portfolio website I made a slideshow with cycle2 carousel with some big images on my work page.

All images are also displayed on the homepage really small.

I would like to make the smaller images on the homepage function as links to the bigger images within the slideshow.

I tried to give all images in the slideshow a different id to link to. But the link always goes to the first image of the slideshow and not the image with the id. Can anyone maybe give me some advice on this?

Thank you,
Noa

Comment: is there any code you could show us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to utilize the cycle2 api to transition the slideshow to the appropriate slide when the user clicks the link. Here's the relative snippet from the api documents:

```
// goto 3rd slide
$('.cycle-slideshow').cycle('goto', 2);
```

You just have to use the index numbers of the slide in question. You would run this code then have the link point to the anchor of the slideshow.

Rest of the documentation on the api can be found here: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/api/

---

**UPDATE**

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    var field = 'slide';
    var url = window.location.href;
    var slideNumber = url.indexOf('?slide');
    if ( slideNumber === -1 ) {
        slideNumber = url.indexOf('&slide');
    }
    if ( slideNumber >= 0 ) {
        $('.cycle-slideshow').cycle('goto', url[slideNumber + 1]);
    }
});
```

Comment: It's is working really well when I make a link on my work page to the slideshow on the same page. But now I'm trying to make a link from the homepage to the slideshow on the work page. But I'm not sure in which document to put the script language because the link first has to go to the work page and after that execute the script part. Do you understand my question?

Comment: You'll need to take a look at the url when someone comes to the page, and determine if they've got the #slideshow or something in the url. And include query parameter for which index to change the slider to so something like: http://www.yourpage.com/#slideshow?slide=2

Then in jQuery(document).ready() do a check on the url to see if a slide is provided and change the slide to the given index. :)

Comment: Added a rough example as an update, there's probably a better way to check for the existence of the query string using a library or something.

Comment: Okay I will take a look at it, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: You're quite welcome. If it works for you be sure to vote up and accept my answer :)